# RPi not broadcasting Static IP in its AP Mode

Tags: pi-3

I have been working on RPi's **AP mode**, everything is working fine, problem is that while RPi broadcasts its AP, the IP i get is not what i mentioned in the **configuration file**.

Anyone here to help me out in this scenario.

Following are the files' info:

**/etc/dnsmasq.conf**

```
interface=lo,ap0
no-dhcp-interface=lo,wlan0
bind-interfaces
server=8.8.8.8 
domain-needed 
bogus-priv
dhcp-range=192.168.33.50,192.168.33.55,24h
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto ap0
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug ap0
iface ap0 inet static
    address 192.168.33.1
    netmask 255.255.255.1
    hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Comment: in /etc/network/Interfaces your netmask value is incorrect.  it should probably be 255.255.255.0.   It may help if you were to actually provide the IP address handed out by the DHCP (if one is received). N.B without DHCP response many computer are configured to use a fallback IP address - don't confuse this as an address provided by DHCP.

Comment: What operating system do you use? It cannot be Raspbian because it uses **dhcpcd** instead of `/etc/network/interfaces` for networking.

Comment: I'm using Stretch for my Raspberry Pi. Thanks.. @Charemer and Ingo, My problem is solved.

Comment: For solving this issue, i restarted the dhcpcd service after configuring the files...